PhpStorm vs Terminal authenticating to BitBucket
I am using PhpStorm as an IDE with a BitBucket repository. To authenticate communicating with the repository (eg push and pull) I have installed git-credential-helper and, in MacOS Terminal, this works fine.
However I get an authentication error when trying to use the Terminal in PhpStorm ("Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443 "). git --config shows the identical result for the directory whether in PhpStorm or MacOS Terminal. git status is also identical.
Whereas I can communicate with the repository by committing in PhpStorm and push in Terminal. This is an irritant.
How can I resolve this?

run following command in PhpStorm's Terminal to verify:
git config --global credential.helper
If it doesn't return osxkeychain, set it by running:
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain

"Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443" suggests a network issue, not anything with credentials or credential helpers. Do you have a proxy?

@JimRedmond From what I can gather, it's Bitbucket's response to a missing app password. There's no proxy and I don't get this error running the same git push from the same directory in MacOS Terminal

@0xn0b174 I've tried this, it initially returned /usr/local/share/gcm-core/git-credential-manager so I ran the 2nd command - warning: credential.helper has multiple values so I added --add but there's no difference, git push works in MacOS Terminal but not PhpStorm Terminal. To be clear, all other local git commands work fine git status etc.

@0xn0b174, I've now got, from git config --list
credential.helper=
credential.helper=/usr/local/share/gcm-core/git-credential-manager
credential.helper=osxkeychain
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
